# Tkinter でラジオボタンの大きさを変更するには？

Tags: python, tkinter

PythonでWindowsアプリのUIを作っています。使用モジュールはTkinterです。

デフォルトではラジオボタンの表示がとても小さいので、大きくしたいのですが、どのようにすればよいかわかりません。
ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらアドバイスいただけませんか？

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes

class showUI:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        font_general = ('Meiryo UI', '14', 'normal')

        try:
            ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
        except:
            pass
        
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('sample')
        root.geometry('500x100')
        
        select = tk.IntVar()
        select.set(0)
        radio0 = tk.Radiobutton(
            root,
            variable=select,
            value=0,
            text='Radio A',
            font=font_general
        )
        radio1 = tk.Radiobutton(
            root,
            variable=select,
            value=1,
            text='Radio B',
            font=font_general
        )
        radio0.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.05)
        radio1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.05)

        root.mainloop()
        self.select = select.get()
        root.destroy()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    showUI()
```

Comment: この辺の記事で、tkinterではなくttkのradiobuttonでstyle.layoutを変更して画像を指定することでもしかしたら何とか出来るかもしれません。[tkinter - Make circle for radio button bigger](https://python-forum.io/thread-2313.html), [How do you change ttk.Radiobutton circle/diamond?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65372273/9014308), [【Python】ttk：tkinterと比べた各ウィジェットの外観と機能面の違い](https://office54.net/python/tkinter/tkinter-ttk-difference), [tkinterとtkinter.ttk　ウィジェットの外観を比べてみた Python](https://www.python-beginners.com/entry/20181228/1546007370) 試してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

これらの記事を応用することで、あらかじめ用意した任意のサイズの画像へ切り替えることが出来ました。
[How do you change ttk.Radiobutton circle/diamond?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65372273/9014308)
[Can't change button font size in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49878388/9014308)
[tkinter.(ttk.)Radiobutton【ラジオボタン ウィジェット】](https://cercopes-z.com/Python/stdlib-tkinter-widget-radiobutton-py.html)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  #### ttk追加
import ctypes

class showUI:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
        except:
            pass
        
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('sample')
        root.geometry('500x100')
        
        select = tk.IntVar()
        select.set(0)
        
        #### Off/Onのイメージ読み取りとラジオボタンへのスタイル設定
        style = ttk.Style(root)
        with open('Off.png', 'rb') as f:
            data_unselected = f.read()
        img_unselected = tk.PhotoImage("radiobutton_unselected", master=root, data=data_unselected)
        with open('On.png', 'rb') as f:
            data_selected = f.read()
        img_selected = tk.PhotoImage("radiobutton_selected", master=root, data=data_selected)
        style.element_create('custom.indicator', 'image', "radiobutton_unselected",
                             ('selected', '!disabled', "radiobutton_selected"))
        style.layout(
            'TRadiobutton',
            [('Radiobutton.padding',
              {'sticky': 'nswe',
               'children': [('custom.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                            ('Radiobutton.focus',
                             {'side': 'left',
                              'sticky': '',
                              'children': [('Radiobutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})])
        ### ttkでのフォント設定に変更
        style.configure('TRadiobutton',font=('Meiryo UI',14,'normal'))
        
        radio0 = ttk.Radiobutton( #### tkからttkに変更、フォントはstyleで変更
            root,
            variable=select,
            value=0,
            text='Radio A'
        )
        radio1 = ttk.Radiobutton( #### tkからttkに変更、フォントはstyleで変更
            root,
            variable=select,
            value=1,
            text='Radio B'
        )
        radio0.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.05)
        radio1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.05)
        
        root.mainloop()
        self.select = select.get()
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    showUI()
```

Off画像

[image: Off画像]

On画像

[image: On画像]

表示結果

[image: 表示結果]

Comment: ありがとうございます！ラジオボタン自体のサイズを変えることはできないけど、画像を与えるということはできるということですね。修正していただいたコードで選択・非選択で画像を切り替えることができ、感動しました。ttkでStyleで見栄えを与える方法は、前によくわからないと挫折したのですが、これを機に積極的に使っていこうと思います。